# how can we perform load test for 50 users simultaneously using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

out of 50 users 10  users should perform one activity and 5 users should perform another and soon. I distributed the users for different activities.

the scenarios as follows:

**Activity**
Full text search                   10 users
Key word Search                     3 users
wild card search                    3 users
logical operator search             4 users
Enable                              5 users
Disable                             5 users
View Config                         5 users
View Log history                    5 users
View Graph                          5 users
View Alerts                         5 users
**Total users                        50 users**

can any please help me for this

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSV Data Set Config. For each thread, one line from a csv file is read and stored in jmeter variables. The threads then can branch depending on the values.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the following Test Elements:

1. [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) - to distribute requests between keyword search, wildcard search, etc.
2. [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) - to set exact load of 50 requests per second (you'll need to put "3000" in "Target throughput" input field.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a ThreadGroup for every type of activity required by the test. If you need custom input data, you can use CSV data to configured outside jmeter for each test.

This way you have all the operations under the same script and just play to execute them.